# HTAccess Redirect on Wrong Folder name

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I've asked this question before but I'm asking again because no one no one could answer it before. I want to redirect the user if he/she types in the wrong folder name. So if they do:

```
www.domain.com/folder
```

I want to redirect them to

```
www.domain.com/Folder
```

So here's the htaccess code in my root directory so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/Front.php$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

What should I append to that to help me redirect if they type in the folder name in lowercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: `RewriteRule ^folder(/.*)?$ /Folder$1 [L,R=301]`